# regex question for parsing xml

Tags: java, html, xml, regex, htmlunit

I'm trying to get the text in between the tags `<dev>Text Here</dev>`:

```
<div id="tt" class="info">
  Text Here
</div>
```

```
Output: Text Here
```

How can I achieve this using regex in java? thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/):

```
 currentPage.getElementById("tt").asXml();
```

```
 currentPage.getElementById("tt").asText(); // returns ""
```

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regular expressions, you can use the following:

```
String s = "<div id=\"tt\" class=\"info\">\n  Text Here   \n</div>";
System.out.println(s);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<div id=\"tt\" class=\"info\">\\s*([^<]+?)\\s*</div>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));  // Text Here
}
```

However, a better solution would be to parse the HTML into XHTML, using [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/index.html), for example, and then extract the required text using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) (`//div[@id = 'tt']/text()`). Something along these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a new JTidy instance and set options
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setXHTML(true); 

    // Parse an HTML page into a DOM document
    URL url = new URL("http://something.com/something.html");       
    Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(url.openStream(), System.out);

    // Use XPath to obtain whatever you want from the (X)HTML
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//div[@id = 'tt']/text()");
    String text = (String)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
    System.out.println(text); // Text Here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't. It's much easier to use a proper parser and just pull out the elements you are interested in. It's extremely difficult to use regular expressions for this kind of thing.

Comment: I have used `asText()` using `HtmlUnit` but it returns empty string `""`

Answer (score 2):

NEVER try to parse XML or HTML using regular expressions.

1. It's theoretically impossible: the grammar of XML and HTML is a richer class of grammar than the grammar that regular expressions can process.
2. You'll get it wrong anyway, for reasons that have nothing to do with the theoretical limitations: there are too many subtleties like whitespace, CDATA sections, comments etc that you need to take into account.
3. There's no shortage of free off-the-shelf parsers that do the job properly, and fast.

Answer (score 1):

Also if it is HTML you are trying to parse or get try Jsoup, http://watchitlater.com/blog/2010/09/jsoup-beautifulsoup-for-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for this, so long as you don't mind doing exactly what you said (and probably not what you meant):

Try the regexp `<div.*>(.*)</div>` on the string:

```
<div id="tt" class="info">
    <a href="../link.htm>Clicky</a>
</div>
```

You'll get the value `<a href="../link.htm>Clicky</a>`, instead of what you want, which is `Clicky`.  Since XML can nest stuff without limit, regular expressions can't match them unless you make certain sacrifices (like handcoding for each level that you want to accomodate).